# getting information about number of chosen files

Tags: php, forms, count

i've created some code

```html
<input class="upload"  type="file" value="choose" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" required>
     ';
 $ghj = count(files);
 
 echo '
 <input type="hidden" name="ghj"  value="'.$ghj.'">
<input type="submit" name="send" class="check-button" value="check">
```

and need really bad to know before submitting how many files was chosen. And it has to be in php variable... i tried everything i know and nothing is working. Could anybody help me?

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941592/php-multiple-file-array

Comment: So i should do something like this? its not working neither:/

$ghj = count($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']);

Answer (score 0):

If you need this information before submitting the form, you'd like to use Javascript instead of PHP.

According to [another Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171013/javascript-get-number-of-files-and-their-filenames-from-input-multiple-elemen), there is a way to get these files using Javascript/jQuery:

Example using jQuery:

```
var files = $(".upload").first().files;
var filesCount = files.length;

alert(filesCount);
```

However, you say you'll need this as an PHP variable. I don't really understand, since you'll need this information before the form submit.

Well, you can use AJAX for PHP to process the information if that's a solution for you:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Example:

```
var files = $(".upload").first().files;
var filesCount = files.length;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'URL_TO_PHP_SCRIPT',
  data: {
      count: filesCount
  }
});
```