# Re-populate input type file in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

In **codeigniter** i have a form which contains some **text and file**(input type=file) fields. Some text fields are **required**. When i fill the form with file but **missed one required field** and submit the form. All fields are again **repopulate the text other than file field** . How can i get the selected files when form submission failed.

I tried `set_value()` but it seems not work.

and one more thing i can upload multiple files at a time:

```
$data = array ( 'name'=>'data_sheet[]',
                        'id'=>'data_sheet',
                        'class'=>'form-control',
                        'value'=>set_value('data_sheet', $data_sheet), 
                        'onchange'=>'validateFileInput(this)',
                      );
                    echo form_upload($data,'','multiple');
```

Here is the validation :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name','name' ,'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('data_sheet','data sheet','trim');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
    {
        $this->template->write_view('content', 'user/user_form',$data,TRUE);
    }
```

When i set the **set_value** like :

```
set_value=json_encode($_FILES)

<input type="file" name="data_sheet[]" value="{"data_sheet":{"name":["download.jpg"],"type":["image\/jpeg"],"tmp_name":["\/tmp\/phpTxQzNe"],"error":[0],"size":[4792]}}" id="data_sheet" class="form-control" onchange="validateFileInput(this)" multiple="">
```

How can i use thos to upload the file

Comment: show us the validation code.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju see the updated code

Comment: show the `form_validation->run() == false)` part

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju check it...

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code to be like this:

```
      $data = array ( 'name'=>'data_sheet[]',
                    'id'=>'data_sheet',
                    'class'=>'form-control',
                    'value'=>$_FILES['data_sheet[]']['tmp_name'],
                    'onchange'=>'validateFileInput(this)',
                  );
                echo form_upload($data,'','multiple');
```

Comment: thank you for your answer it shows error like array to string conversion

Comment: `Message: Undefined index: data_sheet[]`

Comment: What  do you set for name of input file?

Comment: check my question it is like `data_sheet[]`

Comment: For multiple input file, I suggest you go to this url:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941592/php-multiple-file-array

Comment: Multiple File upload is working well but i want get back the file  if validation fails

Comment: when i gave like this `'value'=>json_encode($_FILES)`, able to get the file data's how can use for file upload agian

Comment: can you give the sample of `json_encode` result that you get?