# PHP loop through input fields with same name, upload all

Tags: php, loops, input, upload

I have multiple input fields with the same name. they look like:

```
<input type="hidden" class="image-hidden" name="image-to-upload[]" />
<input type="hidden" class="image-hidden" name="image-to-upload[]" />
<input type="hidden" class="image-hidden" name="image-to-upload[]" />
<input type="hidden" class="image-hidden" name="image-to-upload[]" />
...
...
```

I am uploading with this code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['new-blogpost'])) {
        $img = $_POST['image-to-upload'][0];
        $img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
        $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
        $data = base64_decode($img);
        $file = 'image.jpg';
        $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    };
?>
```

the problem is, this code will only upload the first input fields picture.

How do I have to rewrite my code to upload all input fields? (I know that I have to give my files unique names in that case, but thats no my question. I'm wondering how to tell PHP it has to loop through all the input fields and do the upload.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just loop over the variable `$_POST['image-to-upload']`.  It's an array, so you can go over all the items in it.

Comment: well yes, thanks. but i don't know how to do that :/ tried to figure it out but i don't really understand

Comment: The search for "php loop through array" in google gives this as a first result: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: And you can also check the Documentation here in StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/2213/loops#t=201612261442355323506

Comment: true, i read this, but if i use foreach ($_POST['image-to-upload']) {} i don't know what i have to use as $value. I simply do not understand :/

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Comment: yes, i did and thank you very much, that is pretty amazing, and the comparison was really good to get some understanding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `foreach` loop:

```
$list = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'];

foreach ($list as $value) {
    if ($value == 'banana') {
        continue;
    }
    echo "I love to eat {$value} pie.".PHP_EOL;
}
```

In your example - your array's name is `$_POST['image-to-upload']` so you can loop over it:

```
foreach($_POST['image-to-upload'] as $img) {
    $img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    // $file = 'image.jpg'; // here you need to create the unique filename
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For iterating all the files use foreach loop

```
foreach($_FILES['image-to-upload']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
    {

      //Code

    }
```

See this link for more understanding:

[PHP Multiple File Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941592/php-multiple-file-array)

Comment: Did you read the question? It's not related at all to multiple files uploading

Answer (score 0):

Declare an array and equate it to your post data like `$arr =new array();
$arr = $_POST["img[]"];`
 and with a for loop you can loop through your array