# How to sort a messed array to a more arranged array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like the first picture below. Is it possible to re-arrange the array position like the second picture below? So that it can arranged file0, file1, file2 and so on.

**Multiple Array**

[image]

**Single Array**

[image]

Comment: Do the same indexes correspond to the same file? For example `name[0], error[0], size[0]` is one file and `name[1], error[1], size[1]` is another file? `name`, `error` etc arrays have the same size?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Multiple File Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941592/php-multiple-file-array)

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek yes, `name[0], error[0], size[0] is one file and name[1], error[1], size[1] is another file and so on` but the value of each indexes are different

Comment: @Scoots I dont think the link is going to help me because it does not sort any arrays...it is telling how to upload multiple files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I solved my own answer by sorting like this

```
$count = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
$sort_arr = [];
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
    $sort_arr['file'.$i]['name'] = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
    $sort_arr['file'.$i]['type'] = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];
    $sort_arr['file'.$i]['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $sort_arr['file'.$i]['error'] = $_FILES['file']['error'][$i];
    $sort_arr['file'.$i]['size'] = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];
}
```